# Change CSS Menu hover colours

Tags: jquery, css

I have this CSS for my horizontal menu:

```
.active { /* active/current link */
    background: #666666;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.toggleMenu { /* small screen open menu option/link */
    display: none;
    background: #666666;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

.nav { /* main nav bar */
    list-style: none;
    *zoom: 1;
    background:#f36f25;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav:before,.nav:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}
nav, ul, li, a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav > li:hover { /* main link hover */
    background: #666666;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.nav:after {
    clear: both;
}
.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 12em;
}
.nav a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color:#fff;
}
.nav li {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}
.nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav > li > .parent {
    background-image: url("/images/downArrow.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
.nav > li > a {
    display: block;
}
.nav li  ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
.nav > li.hover > ul {
    left: 0;
}
.nav li li.hover ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.nav li li a { /* sub menu list */
    display: block;
    background: #F36F25;
    position: relative;
    z-index:100;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.nav li li.hover a { /* sub menu list hover */
    background:#666666;
}
.nav li li li.hover a { /* sub sub menu list hover */
    background:#F36F25;
    color:#ffffff;
    z-index:200;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.nav li li li a { /* sub sub menu list */
    background:#F36F25;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    .active {
        display: block;
    }
    .nav {
        border-top: none;
    }
    .nav > li {
        display: block;
        border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    }
    .nav > li > .parent {
        background-position: 95% 50%;
    }
    .nav li li .parent {
        background-image: url("/images/downArrow.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 95% 50%;
    }
    .nav ul {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
   .nav > li.hover > ul , .nav li li.hover ul {
        position: static;
    }
}
```

but i can't work out how to change the sub sub menu background and hover background colours

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UY7z4/1/

UPDATE:

This is the sub menus:

```
.nav li li a { /* sub menu list */
    display: block;
    background: #F36F25;
    position: relative;
    z-index:100;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.nav li li.hover a { /* sub menu list hover */
    background:#666666;
}
.nav li li li a { /* sub sub menu list */
    background:#F36F25;
}
.nav li li li.hover a { /* sub sub menu list hover */
    background:#666666;
    color:#ffffff;
    z-index:200;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

so the sub menu should have `#F36F25` background and `#666666` hover background

and the sub sub menu should have `#F36F25` background and `#666666` hover background

Comment: This fiddle does not show any submenu on hover, all I am seeing is the service item change background colour

Comment: Why aren't you using different class, according to the element's level. That would be the best practice I think

Comment: working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UY7z4/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this selector for submenu:

```
.nav >li ul > li  a {
  background:red;
}
.nav >li ul >li:hover > a {
  background:blue;
}
```

And for sub submenu this:

```
.nav >li ul > li ul li a {
  background:pink;
}
.nav >li ul > li ul li:hover a {
  background:brown;
}
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/UY7z4/11/

Comment: the sub sub menu isn't showing hover background, check my edit

Comment: @charlie now I include the sub sub menu

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer here

http://jsfiddle.net/UY7z4/19/

```
.nav > li > ul > li.hover > a { /* sub menu list hover */
    background:#666666;
}
.nav > li > ul > li.hover > ul > li { /* sub sub menu list hover */
    background:#F36F25;
}
.nav > li > ul > li.hover > ul > li:hover a {
    background:#666;
    color:#ffffff;
    z-index:200;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: i want the sub sub menu to have #F36F25 background colour and #666666 on hover

Comment: ok so change the colour to your likings, the point I am making is you used .hover when you should be using :hover

Comment: but the sub submenu background needs to be #F36F25 and its showing as #666666 - it should only be #666666 on hover

Comment: it is grey when you hover it. When you hover the sub sub, it is also hovering on the sub menu since sub sub is contained within the sub

Comment: how can i make it so its as my previous comment?

Comment: nearly... background is #f36f25 and on hover it changes to #666666 on all links

Comment: So when VOIP is hovered, you want telecom to be orange and VOIP to be grey? Be more clear on which item should be what, use the words that's in the fiddle

Comment: hover on services - change to orange. hover on telecoms - change to orange and keep services orange. hover on VoIP - change to orange and keep service and telecoms orange

Comment: so keep everything orange?? just remove the css for the hover style or remove all instances of background:#666666; answer is updated with fiddle

Comment: ah sorry, no everything orange then on hover #666666

Comment: everything to grey or what? be more specific, when I hover VOIP, what are the colours of each item?? and can you add classes to the html markup?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43785/discussion-between-charlie-and-huangism)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add:

```
/*for hover*/
.nav li ul li:hover {
    background: #666666;
    text-decoration:none;
}
/*for background*/
.nav li ul li{
    background: #F36F25 ;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```