# CSS3: how to correctly use :hover to modify other elements' styles?

Tags: css, hover

I'm confused about using the pseudo-class `:hover`.

In the following HTML, `:hover` works as expected for the `ul` elements, but not for the `div` ones:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset:"utf-8" />
<style>

#div1:hover #div2 { 
  color: green;
}

#ul2 {
  display: none;
}

#ul1:hover #ul {
  display:block;
}    

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id='div1'>
If I hover this, then the next div should change color to green...
</div>

<div id='div2'>
But it doesn't change colors!
</div>

<ul id='ul1'>
<li>If I hover this, then ul2 shows up</li>
<ul id='ul2'>
<li>We're showing up!</li>
<li>We're showing up!</li>
</ul>
<li>etc.</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

`#div2` will only turn green if I change this line `#div1:hover #div2 {` to `#div1:hover + #div2 {` (notice the plus sign "+"). I don't understand, why is the "+" needed? In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749818/change-css-menu-hover-colours), the code even uses `nav ul li:hover > ul`. What is the `>` for?

Summing up my question: *What are the rules for making `:hover` change in CSS another element's syle?*

Comment: thats not working in pure css, you have to use javascript (jquery) for that

Comment: @FelixHäberle Thanks! But why is that? Is there a problem in browser implementation?

Comment: its in case of the specification of css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand, why is the "+" needed?

The `+` stands for the adjacent sibling selector, which one use when target an element that is an immediate *sibling* element, as the opposite to a child element

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

> What is the > for?

The `>` stands for a child selector, and target the immediate children only

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

---

*As a side note, it is invalid to have an `ul` (in this case the `<ul id='ul2'>`) as a direct child of another `ul`, the inner one should be wrapped in a `li`*

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I've been struggling with this for the past 2 hours! So, that's why. I'm choosing your reply as the answer, but StackOverflow forbids me to select it before 3 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Your #div2 have to be a child of #div1 if you want it to work like that

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do? If want use same hover form both div's, so maybe something like this.

```
#div1:hover, #div2:hover {color: green;}
```